# match = time_re.match(value) TypeError: Expected string or buffer

Tags: python, django, django-models

my models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')
    hours = models.TimeField('Working Hours')
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

I'm working on Windows-7, I've added a field named `hours` then when making migrations django asks me to provide a one-time default value, I've provide `'0'`. After that I've tried to migrate my changes then it gives me above traceback(I'm not able to copy whole traceback).

I've tried to remove the field and reinsert again but django again and again prompts me same above error. Can any one please tell me how to fix it?

I've deleted my migrations file and after that I run commands- `'python manage.py makemigrations'` and `'python manage.py migrate'` but it doesn't effect anyway. I've also used `'syncdb'`. Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open your database and then open **django_migrations** table, remove rows that contains migration name and after rows of this, then recreate migration and set an valid value.
**Note**: you can set default value before create default value similar below:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date', auto_now=True)
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME', default=datetime.time(0))
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME', default=datetime.time(0))
    hours = models.TimeField('Working Hours', default=datetime.time(0))
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

Comment: But I'm using sqlite which is built-in django. I don't where I've to open db api. Should I've to delete my migrations file?

Comment: Use sqlite-man or other sqlite management program, yes you must delete old migration file. also you can set `default` value for `hour` field and then run `./manage.py makemigrations` command.

Comment: How can I install other database then sqlite like Postgre Sql? on my current project. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Read more about django db connection settings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: I've deleted migrations files and run command - python manage.py migrate. But it still shows the same error...

Comment: What is default value of `hour` field?

Comment: `'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py'` - is the location which it shows on error screen.

Comment: when asking u for default value answer by `datetime.time(0)`

Comment: @Mohsen looks like it's migration failed, so there will be no track of the failed migration in django_migrations and using ./manage.py sqlshell will be universal way to call db client